# Garbage collecting Redux/Flux stores

Tags: reactjs, flux, redux

I'm in a project where we're currently using Redux for state management in our React-based Single page application, and we've run into an issue regarding when/how to clean out unused data from our stores (technically sub-state on or global Redux store).

For example we have a calendar "store" which looks

```
calendar = {
    "2015-11-06": {
        // Loads of data
    },
    ... // More dates
}
```

Mostly we only care about a single date at the time, but there are cases where there are different components that needs different calendar date at the same time.

The question is: Is there some kind of strategy to "garbage collect" stores?

My initial thought is that components that need a specific calendar date will have to "reserve" that date and when it's unmounted, it'll remove its reservation. That way, when we reach some kind of size limit we can just remove all date that aren't reserved by any component.

It's a bit of a hassle though since it adds the need for components to handle "reservations" when fetching a date and when the component unmounts.

Is this a feasible strategy or is there a better alternative?

Comment: So if someone went back and forth between two calendar dates, you would reload the data for that date? You might want to evaluate whether you're actually storing enough data on the client to impact performance. Another strategy is to keep an array of the dates (the string keys) that are active, and have your reducer only build the large object with keys corresponding to the dates in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good use-case for a [WeakSet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet) or a [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap).

> WeakMap holds references to its keys weakly, meaning that if there are
>   no other references to one of its keys, the object is subject to
>   garbage collection.

Comment: That sounds very interesting, but we use Seamless Immutable for our state, e.g. in our reducers, and it doesn't support weak sets/maps AFAIK :(

Comment: I know it's been a long time this has been posted, but for anybody finding this:
You should not use WeakMap for things labeled with strings (or numbers etc). String will never ever be cleared so the WeakMap will not free the memory once something is no longer used. Why? Because WeakMap frees the memory if the reference to the entry is completely gone. If you assign a key like `let key = 'myKey';` and then remove the key `key = null;`, you can still reassign it `key = 'myKey'` and it will match the reference.

Comment: Good point and this answer is quite old, I think I knew less about Redux at the time, which wouldn't be the right match for WeakSet/Map I think. The user should fire actions as necessary to cleanup store data.

Answer (score 0):

The key to all of this lies in a combination of this statement:

> Mostly we only care about a single date at the time, but there are cases where there are different components that needs different calendar date at the same time.

...and how we think about state in an architecture like Flux/Redux.

There's nothing stopping you from restructuring your existing data store like so:

```
calendar = {
    mainDate: {
        date: "2015-11-06",
        // Loads of data
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you hit one of those special cases where you need more than one date, you issue an action that replaces the `calendar` state with something that looks like this:

```
calendar = {
    mainDate: {
        date: "2015-11-06",
        // Loads of data
    },
    otherDate: {
        date: "2016-02-29",
        // Other data. Perhaps even less than the loads you'd have in mainDate
    }
}
```

Somewhere along the line, your components will decide for themselves whether they need to look at `mainDate` or `otherDate`. (They may very well extract the appropriate one and then pass the contents down to their child components; you may want to introduce an abstraction layer here.)

And when the other component is done using the other date, it'll issue another action that generates:

```
calendar = {
    mainDate: {
        date: "2015-11-06",
        // Loads of data
    }
}
```

...thus automatically taking care of your garbage collection concern.

Obviously, there's a lot of implementation detail to be worked out here, but that's specific to your situation. The key concept is to contain all the state (and *only* the state) that you need to run the app at any given time, and use actions to make the transition from one state to another.